# How to Display Toast Notification in PHP when Form is submitted and went to new URL

Tags: php, forms, notifications, toast

on my page when the user submits a form it sends details to my email and went to a new URL.

after the user went t the new URL I want there to show the user about that form that your form is submitted in a toast notification

PHP script for form send via email is this

```php
<?php

if (isset($_POST["sendmessage"])) {
    $fname = $_POST["fullname"];

    $fnumber = $_POST["phonenumber"];

    $femail = $_POST["fullemail"];

    $fsubject = $_POST["fullsubject"];

    $fmessage = $_POST["fullmessage"];

    $status = "";
    $subject = "Contact Form | MAKT Website";
    $body =
        '<p style="font-size: 18px;">New Message has been submitted from your website contact form</p><br>';
    $body =
        "<br> Below Are the details for the query <br> <b>Name: </b> " .
        "<br> <b>Full Name: </b>\n $fname" .
        "<br>  <b>Phone: </b>: $fnumber" .
        "<br> <b>Email: </b>  $femail" .
        "<br>  <b>Subject: </b> $fsubject" .
        "<br>  <b>Customer Message: </b> $fmessage";

    $email_to = "m.ahmed4821@l.com";

    $email_from = "no-reply@mrmakt.com"; // Enter Sender Email
    $sender_name = "M.A.K.T- Website"; // Enter Sender Name
    require "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "mrmakt.com"; // Enter Your Host/Server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "no-reply@mrmakt.com"; // Enter Sender Email
    $mail->Password = "";
    //If SMTP requires TLS encryption then remove comment from it
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port = 26;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->From = $email_from;
    $mail->FromName = $sender_name;
    $mail->Sender = $email_from; // indicates ReturnPath header
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email_from, "No Reply"); // indicates ReplyTo headers
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($email_to);
    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        $status = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
         ?>
         <script>
         location.replace("index.php?message=your-message-has-been-sent") 
         </script>

        <?php
    }
} else {
    $msg = "Something Went Wrong. Please try again";
}
?>
```

after sending the form to new URL I am getting the value using this below ode and trying to display the toast also using the below code

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $querysubmitted = "Thank You....! Your Message has been sent|.";
} 
?>

<?php if ($querysubmitted) { ?>
    <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <img src="imgs/MAKT_FALCON_PMG.png" class="rounded me-2" alt="MAKT_LOGO">
            <strong class="me-auto">M.A.K.T</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>

        <div class="toast-body">

        <?php echo htmlentities($querysubmitted); ?>
        
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Please help me with that

thanks in advance

Comment: Did u get the answer

Comment: if u have a  answer please post

Comment: no i did not get the answer @AnandhKrishnan